# NameValuePair how to send blanks

Tags: android

I have a requirement to send some values to a service via HTTP POST.  One of the parameters that gets sent must contain blanks.  It is the "Key" nvp.  But the service always returs a unsuccessful message, as soon as I add a value it work.

Now here is the catch, when the request is done to the same service via iphone device it works just fine when they send BLANKS, am I missing something in my request to allow blank values to be sent via NameVauePair?

Here is my NaveValuePair's

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","1"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uId",android_id));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Key", " "));  // This value must be BLANKS
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Rate","0"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Notes", notes));
```

Here is my POST request

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();                        
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(context.getResources()                 
        .getString(R.string.url_event_rating));                             

try {                                                                   

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "utf-8"));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request                                          
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);                 
    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response                   
            .getEntity());                                                    

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {                                   
    Log.d("ClientProtocolException", e.getMessage());                     
} catch (IOException e) {                                               
    Log.d("IOException", e.getMessage());                                 
}
```

Comment: This question is in a large part about your web service, that you haven't provided any code for. That makes it very difficult to answer. Have you tried passing the empty string `""`?

Comment: Have you tried `null`?

Comment: I dont have access to the service, I just have to interface with it.  But what I hear is that the iOS version of the app is able to send in blanks.

Comment: Are you sure 'key' is mandatory even blank? According to the documentation you can set a `BasicNameValuePair`'s value as `null`. Have you tried that already?

Comment: I just tried null and it also did not work.

Comment: Isn't it just encoded at %20...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `SP` instead of a literal space character.  This is the syntax given to you by BasicNameValuePair: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html (specifies a general overview of the class) and http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2 (specifies the tokens accepted).

Essentially, you want to insert `SP` instead of `" "`, according to what I've read on the topic.

**Edit:** According to the second link above: `SP = <US-ASCII SP, space (32)>`. Essentially, either place a character whose value is 32 (decimal) or 0x20 (hex). Or, change your encoding in `UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "utf-8")` to `"US-ASCII"`.

Comment: According to the second link above: `SP  = <US-ASCII SP, space (32)>`.  Essentially, either place a character whose value is 32 (decimal) or 0x20 (hex).  Or, change your encoding in `UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "utf-8")` to `"US-ASCII"`.

Comment: UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "utf-8") was fundamental for my json value pairs to pass

Answer (score 0):

While we send a POST request there are field in HTTP Headers to be set, like the `Content-Type` field with value `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, which is default type. We should whatsoever encode the `value` field of request body before sending it. [**`URLEncoder.encode(String s, String charsetName`**)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) functions encode a string with given `charsetName` i.e, `'utf-8'`. The encoding used by default is based on a very early version of the general URI [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) rules.

one encoding example: a string like `My Name is "Marshal"` will be encoded as:
`My%20Name%20is%20%22Marshal%22`.

So, the safest way is to set `(name, value)` pair after encoding with this function. That is:

```
          value = URLEncoder.encode(value, "utf-8");
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value));
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, there might be other ways to get this to work but the following code is what worked for me.

I got it to work using the following approach.

```
String blanks = " ";  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Key", blanks.replaceAll(" ", "%20")));
```

Hope this helps someone who has encountered the same problem.

Comment: Your step is working for this scenario, but it is not actually a general solution. I have seen some others to do so, that is why i am back here to mention. Check my answer.